# STM32F4 Discovery simple, minimal toolchain on Mac OS X

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm in the process of learning to program the STM32F4 on a discovery board. It has been frustrating to get a toolchain going to say the least. I have the necessary utilities to program and debug the board (st-link, arm-none-eabi), have established communication with the board, and loaded the blinky example.

First of all, I have a Mac and I already know that limits me as far as support goes. Mbed also doesn't support this board very well. All I want is to get the bare minimum source files I need and learn to program this board from scratch. By that I mean I'd like to download the STM cube firmware files and extract the minimum source files I need to access all the different parts of the chip and board (registers, pins, etc.). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [STM32CubeF4](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243) on the ST website, that's a plain zip file with the CMSIS and HAL libraries, board support drivers, and tons of examples.

But check out the latest version of [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/stm32cube-pr2) too, it has recently got a multiplatform installer that's supposed to work on a Mac.

```
Supported operating systems and architectures

 * Windows(R) XP: 32-bit (x86)
 * Windows(R) 7: 32-bit (x86), 64-bit (x64)
 * Windows(R) 8: 32-bit (x86), 64-bit (x64)
 * Linux: 64-bit (x64) (tested on RedHat, Ubuntu and Fedora)
 * Mac OS X Yosemite or newer

Software requirements

Java Run Time Environment (minimum version 1.7.0_45)
```

Comment: Awesome, It had been a while since I last checked updates on their Cube releases. In any case the other issue I'm having is finding an IDE setup that works with Cube MX for Mac OS X. If you or anyone knows about any solutions that would be awesome!